# How to disable update between Datagrid from Textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have this form.

[image]

**Summary**

On selected record from Datagrid, the right form will fill the TextBoxes.

**Problem**

Notice this:

[image]

When I untick the checkbox, the DataGrid gets updated too..

[image]

The DataGrid should only be updated on Click of a button.

**Question**

How do I remove the update between the DataGrid and the form? So instead, if I untick the box, the value remains as the original value. I do not need this automatic update.

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!--DataGrid View for record selection-->
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <StackPanel>
            <DataGrid x:Name="FSQMGrid" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding FSQMRecords}"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGrid}"
                      >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DocumentReference}" Header="Document Reference"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DocumentTitle}" Header="Document Title"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path}" Header="Path" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IssueNumber}" Header="Issue Number"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IssueDate}" Header="Issue Date"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NextReviewDate}" Header="Next Review Date"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Archived}" Header="Archived"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UserIDModified}" Header="User ID Modified" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UsernameModified}" Header="User Modified"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>


            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

    <!--Editing Data-->


    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">

        <materialDesign:Card Padding="20"
                             Margin="0 0 0 0">

            <StackPanel>

                <TextBlock Margin="16 16 12 8"
                           FontSize="16">Selected Record</TextBlock>

                <Separator Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignLightSeparator}" Background="LightGray"/>


                <CheckBox Content="Archived"
                          IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=FSQMGrid, Path=SelectedItem.Archived}"
                          Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignAccentCheckBox}" 
                          Margin="0 0 0 0"/>

                <StackPanel Margin="0 10 0 0">

                    <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Document Reference"
                             Text="{Binding ElementName=FSQMGrid, Path=SelectedItem.DocumentReference, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"/>

                    <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Document Title"
                             Text="{Binding ElementName=FSQMGrid, Path=SelectedItem.DocumentTitle, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Margin="0 10 0 0"
                             Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" />

                    <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Section"
                             Text="{Binding ElementName=FSQMGrid, Path=SelectedItem.SectionNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Margin="0 10 0 0"
                             Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" />

                    <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Issue Number"
                             Text="{Binding ElementName=FSQMGrid, Path=SelectedItem.IssueNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Margin="0 10 0 0"
                             Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" />

                    <DatePicker materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Issue Date"
                                Text="{Binding ElementName=FSQMGrid, Path=SelectedItem.IssueDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Margin="0 10 0 0"
                                Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintDatePicker}"/>

                    <DatePicker materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Review Date"
                                Text="{Binding ElementName=FSQMGrid, Path=SelectedItem.NextReviewDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Margin="0 10 0 0"
                                Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintDatePicker}"/>

                    <Button Command="{}"
                                Content="Save Information"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Margin="50,20,0,0"/>

                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You are editing the same property of the same object that you see in the `DataGrid` so the data is updated regardless of whether you click the `Button`. You may want to implement `IEditableObject`.

Comment: What's your point?

Comment: Your question original was about how to disable the `DataGrid` from being updated when you edit the object that's displayed in it.

Comment: @mm8 Where would I implement the `IEditableObject`?

Comment: In the data object `FSQMRecord` or whatever you call it.

Comment: @mm8 I'll research how to do it. But thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are editing the same property of the same object that you see in the `DataGrid` so the data is indeed updated regardless of whether you click the `Button`.

You could consider to implement the [IEditableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) interface in your data object class. It provides functionality to commit or rollback changes to an object that is used as a data source.

The other option would be to edit a copy of the object that you bind to in the `DataGrid` and then update the latter when when the button is actually clicked.

Comment: What do you mean by `edit a copy of the object that you bind to in the DataGrid`?

Comment: Ëxactly what I say, i.e. instead of binding the textboxes to the `SelectedItem` of the `DataGrid`, you could bind to another view model property that you set to a copy of the selected item. Bind the `SelectedItem` to a view model property and then create the copy in the setter of this one.

Answer (score 0):

- The binding source in the Datagrid and the binding source of the selectedRecord are the same object that implements the inotifyPropertyChanged interface.So, if you update this object anywhere, it's going to synchronize on the view.
- This is a button-click updated solution written in the PRISM framework.

like this:

```
public class DataGridViewModel:ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataGridRowItem> Source { get; }

   public ICommand SelectedCommand =>new DelegateCommand<DataGridRowItem>(item =>
   {
       var clone = new DataGridRowItem()
       {
           Archived =  item.Archived
       };
       var vm = new SelectedRecordViewModel()
       {
           Data = clone,
           SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
           {
               item.Archived = clone.Archived;
           })
       };
       var selectedRecord = new Window();
       selectedRecord.DataContext = vm;
       selectedRecord.Show();
   });  

}

public class SelectedRecordViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public DataGridRowItem Data { get; set; }

    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
}

public class DataGridRowItem : ViewModel
{
    private bool archived;

    public bool Archived
    {
        get => archived;
        set => this.SetValue(ref archived, value);
    }


}
```

ps:The solution mentioned by @mm8 is better